# I am unable to install Force.com extension in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, eclipse-neon, force.com

While trying to add Force.com extension in Eclipse Neon i am facing the below issue. Please assist.

[image: Error]

Comment: The current release is Eclipse 2019-06. With Eclipse Neon you are 3 years and 6 releases behind. Please upgrade. If the issues can be reproduced in Eclipse 2019-06, report it to the owner of the Force.com plug-in with the details and the error log.

Comment: Eclipse is being end-of-lifed as a Salesforce IDE. Highly recommended that you upgrade to VIsual Studio Code, Illuminated Cloud, or another currently-supported application.